# Receiving null value when trying to pass Cypress selector to custom cypress command

Tags: cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I am trying to add a custom command to my Cypress framework to check if elements are enabled/disabled.

Here is my attempted custom command in `commands.js`:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('isEnabled', (element) => {
    element.invoke('attr', 'class').then(classAttribute => {
        if (classAttribute.includes('mat-button-disabled')) {
            // do something
        }
    });
});
```

And I am trying to call this command through my step defintion here:

```
cy.isEnabled(widgets.getPaginatorLast());
```

And here is my page object model:

```
getPaginatorLast () {
    return cy.get('.mat-paginator-navigation-last');
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

> Timed out retrying after 20000ms: cy.invoke() errored because your
> subject is: null. You cannot invoke any functions such as attr on a
> null value.
>
> If you expect your subject to be null, then add an assertion such as:
>
> cy.wrap(null).should('be.null')

If I update the `isEnabled()` command to directly use the element like below, rather than pass in the element via my step defintion, then the class attribute is being picked up:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('isEnabled', (element) => {
    widgets.getPaginatorLast().invoke('attr', 'class').then(classAttribute => {
        if (classAttribute.includes('mat-button-disabled')) {
            // do something
        }
    });
});
```

The only change I made is replace `element` with `widgets.getPaginatorLast()`.
I don't know why I'm getting the null error though because that's the value I'm passing in.

Can someone please tell me why this is happening, & what changes are required to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Cypress custom commands should be chained like this

```js
widgets.getPaginatorLast().isEnabled()
```

and the custom command

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('isEnabled', {prevSubject:true}, (element) => {
  if (element.hasClass('mat-button-disabled')) {
    // do something
  }
})
```

The `// do something` is called a "side effect", and should really be done outside the `isEnabled()` method

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('isEnabled', {prevSubject:true}, (element) => {
  return !element.hasClass('mat-button-disabled')
})

widgets.getPaginatorLast().isEnabled().then(enabled => {
  if (enabled) {
    // do something
  }
})
```

Comment: why `// do something` can be done inside a command? Do you have any explanations or doc links?

Comment: Just common sense really. If you name a command `isEnabled` then it should do what it says.

Answer (score 0):

[Cypress' `.get()` command yields a JQuery element](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Yields), and not a Cypress-ready element. So, your `getPaginatorLast()` function returns a JQuery element. In order to easily use this in a Cypress chain, we just need to wrap it with [`cy.wrap()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wrap). The reason substituting the command works is because it is directly chained into the command, instead of resolving as a JQuery element (I'm probably misusing terms here).

```
Cypress.Commands.add('isEnabled', (element) => {
    cy.wrap(element).invoke('attr', 'class').then(classAttribute => {
        if (classAttribute.includes('mat-button-disabled')) {
            // do something
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If the `isEnabled` will be a chained command then the `prevSubject` will need to be added to the custom command to be used as `getPaginatorLast().isEnabled()`, right?

Comment: Hmm.. from OPs example, it looked like they just wanted to do `cy.isEnabled(widgets.getPaginatorLast())`, so they wouldn't need to write the command as a child command. But yes, if they wanted to do `getPaginatorLast().isEnabled()`, then they would need to turn `isEnabled` into a child command.

Comment: That is true. I made an incorrect assumption on my part.

Comment: @agoff, are you sure it's really possible to pass a chain into a custom command as an argument? Have you ever tried this way? It looks like you would have to have 2 active chains at the moment that is not allowed in Cypress.

Comment: It is definitely possible. Look at the Cypress documentation for dual commands -> their example says that if _some element_ is passed in, they start a new `cy.wrap()` chain. https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Dual-Commands